# Can you explain what happens here (gmail dot trick generator)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I literally don't understand

```
def dot_trick(handle):
    f = lambda s:s[11:] and [s[0]+w+x for x in f(s[1:]) for w in('.','')] or [s]
    return f(handle)
```

found it on the internet, it generates all *'gmail dot trick'* email variations

this seems like magic in such compact form, can someone explain me what happens here step by step, please? or maybe rephrase it without lambda function

Comment: It mainly uses the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator) variant implemented with logical operators, and a simple recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mainly uses list comprehension and [ternary operators implemented with binary operators](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator)

The pattern it uses it's deprecated, since the builtin syntax for the ternary operator has been introduced in [PEP 308](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html) on the release of [`Python 2.5`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew).

Furthermore

```
s[11:] and [s[0]+w+x for x in f(s[1:]) for w in('.','')] or [s]
```

can be split into:

```
def f(s)
    if len(s[11:]) > 0:
        lst = []
        for w in (".",''):
            for x in f(s[1:]): #s[:1] removes first character
                lst.append(s[0] + w + x)
        return lst
    return [s]
```

here is what it shows with the [`libcst`](https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST) library:

```
>>> print(libcst.tools.dump(cst.parse_expression("s[11:] and [s[0]+w+x for x in f(s[1:]) for w in('.','')] or [s]")))
BooleanOperation(
  left=BooleanOperation(
    left=Subscript(
      value=Name(
        value='s',
      ),
      slice=[
        SubscriptElement(
          slice=Slice(
            lower=Integer(
              value='11',
            ),
            upper=None,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    operator=And(),
    right=ListComp(
      elt=BinaryOperation(
        left=BinaryOperation(
          left=Subscript(
            value=Name(
              value='s',
            ),
            slice=[
              SubscriptElement(
                slice=Index(
                  value=Integer(
                    value='0',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          operator=Add(),
          right=Name(
            value='w',
          ),
        ),
        operator=Add(),
        right=Name(
          value='x',
        ),
      ),
      for_in=CompFor(
        target=Name(
          value='x',
        ),
        iter=Call(
          func=Name(
            value='f',
          ),
          args=[
            Arg(
              value=Subscript(
                value=Name(
                  value='s',
                ),
                slice=[
                  SubscriptElement(
                    slice=Slice(
                      lower=Integer(
                        value='1',
                      ),
                      upper=None,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        inner_for_in=CompFor(
          target=Name(
            value='w',
          ),
          iter=Tuple(
            elements=[
              Element(
                value=SimpleString(
                  value="'.'",
                ),
              ),
              Element(
                value=SimpleString(
                  value="''",
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  operator=Or(),
  right=List(
    elements=[
      Element(
        value=Name(
          value='s',
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

And here is what it prints for the ast builtin library:

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse("s[11:] and [s[0]+w+x for x in f(s[1:]) for w in('.','')] or [s]")))
Module(body=[Expr(value=BoolOp(op=Or(), values=[BoolOp(op=And(), values=[Subscript(value=Name(id='s', ctx=Load()), slice=Slice(lower=Constant(value=11)), ctx=Load()), ListComp(elt=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Subscript(value=Name(id='s', ctx=Load()), slice=Constant(value=0), ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Name(id='w', ctx=Load())), op=Add(), right=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())), generators=[comprehension(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), iter=Call(func=Name(id='f', ctx=Load()), args=[Subscript(value=Name(id='s', ctx=Load()), slice=Slice(lower=Constant(value=1)), ctx=Load())], keywords=[]), ifs=[], is_async=0), comprehension(target=Name(id='w', ctx=Store()), iter=Tuple(elts=[Constant(value='.'), Constant(value='')], ctx=Load()), ifs=[], is_async=0)])]), List(elts=[Name(id='s', ctx=Load())], ctx=Load())]))], type_ignores=[])
```

Comment: thank you! _#[expression]_ _and_ _[on_true]_ _or_ _[on_false]_ this pattern really confused me, i mean, who decided to use **and** instead of something more clear like **then** for example. :D

Comment: it is explained in [*data structures* part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions). It states: `When used as a general value and not as a Boolean, the return value of a short-circuit operator is the last evaluated argument.`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it could look like in a readable form:

```
def gen_dot_trick(handle):
    if len(handle) <= 11: 
        # stop recursion at the last character of the user name
        # 11 is the length of "X@gmail.com"
        yield handle
    else:
        first, rest = handle[0], handle[1:]
        for sub in gen_dot_trick(rest):
            # with and without the dot after the first char
            yield first + '.' + sub
            yield first       + sub

def dot_trick(handle):
    return list(gen_dot_trick(handle))
```